# Longest palindrome: My program get runtime error in leetcode but it returns right answer on my laptop

Tags: c++, algorithm

My program is below:

```
string longestPalindrome(string s) {
if(s.size() <=1 )
    return s;
bool isPalindrome[s.size()][s.size()];
for( int i=0; i < s.size(); ++i ){
    isPalindrome[i][i]=true;
    isPalindrome[i+1][i]=true;
}
int longestPalindromeLength=0;
int startIndex=0;
for( int i=2; i<= s.size(); ++i){//子串长度
    for( int j=0; j <=s.size()-i;++j ){//每个起始位置
        int k=j+i-1;
        if( s[j]==s[k] ){
            if(isPalindrome[j+1][k-1]== true){
                isPalindrome[j][k]=true;
                if( i > longestPalindromeLength ){
                    longestPalindromeLength=i;
                    startIndex=j;
                }
            }else{
                isPalindrome[j][k]=false;
            }
        }else{
            isPalindrome[j][k]=false;
        }
    }
}
return s.substr(startIndex,longestPalindromeLength);
```

}

The test case is:

> azwdzwmwcqzgcobeeiphemqbjtxzwkhiqpbrprocbppbxrnsxnwgikiaqutwpftbiinlnpyqstkiqzbggcsdzzjbrkfmhgtnbujzszxsycmvipjtktpebaafycngqasbbhxaeawwmkjcziybxowkaibqnndcjbsoehtamhspnidjylyisiaewmypfyiqtwlmejkpzlieolfdjnxntonnzfgcqlcfpoxcwqctalwrgwhvqvtrpwemxhirpgizjffqgntsmvzldpjfijdncexbwtxnmbnoykxshkqbounzrewkpqjxocvaufnhunsmsazgibxedtopnccriwcfzeomsrrangufkjfzipkmwfbmkarnyyrgdsooosgqlkzvorrrsaveuoxjeajvbdpgxlcrtqomliphnlehgrzgwujogxteyulphhuhwyoyvcxqatfkboahfqhjgujcaapoyqtsdqfwnijlkknuralezqmcryvkankszmzpgqutojoyzsnyfwsyeqqzrlhzbc

When I run the code above in leetcode, it gives runtime error. But when I test it on my laptop, It gives the right answer: `"sooos"`

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: `isPalindrome[i+1][i]=true;` when `i` can equal `s.size() - 1` is UB (`i+1` is `s.size()` - setting the element one past the end of an array is UB). This is a comment not an answer as I haven't checked the rest of the code for similar issues.

Comment: `bool isPalindrome[s.size()][s.size()]` uses variable length array **extension**. And that array is only partially initialized.

Comment: That code is pretty inefficient. This problem could be solved in `O(n)` using manachers algorithm

Comment: How can you read such messy code? The parts I understand the best are `//子串长度` and `//每个起始位置` and I don't read Chinese! Rewrite you code to split it in independent, side-effectless functions and classes, each with a unique responsability, functions that you can **test**.

Answer (score 0):

You probably get a runtime error because this leetcode is an environment with limited resources while your laptop is not. Your implementation uses O(N^2) memory and the environment does not allow that.

There are more efficient solution to this classic problem and you should probably change your approach.

Answer (score 0):

1. "bool isPalindrome[s.size()][s.size()];" It is not allowed to define an array on the stack, which size will be defined at run time.
2. Perhaps leetcode accepts the array. But the following loop writes true to positions, which are out of range of the array.